# pycharm python3 error on input

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, input, pycharm

[image]I have this test code:

```
inputs = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(n)
print(inputs)
```

When I input 3 4 in the console below; I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Labhesh/PycharmProjects/algotoolbox/assignment1/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    inputs = list(map(int, input().split()))
  File "<string>", line 1
    3 4
     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I run the same code from command line, there are no issues:

```
>> python3 test.py
>> 3 4
>> [3, 4]
```

Is there some special setting I have to do to make this simple code work in PyCharm?

**EDIT**

It seems that in pycharm project interpreter is not the same as run configuration.
To set Run configuration - use Run --> Edit Configuration and then choose the python interpreter.

You can also do

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

to print the runtime version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that PyCharm may be using a 2.x version of Python.

**When run using python 3.5 in PyCharm:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 59807 --file C:/src/testcode/test.py
pydev debugger: process 12684 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 163.10154.50)
3 4
[3, 4]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**When run using Python 2.7 in PyCharm:**

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 59813 --file C:/src/testcode/test.py 
pydev debugger: process 16920 is connecting

QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
Connected to pydev debugger (build 163.10154.50)
3 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 974, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/src/testcode/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    inputs = list(map(int, input().split()))
  File "<string>", line 1
    3 4
      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: see the screenshot I just added (to my original post), the project interpreter is 3.5

Comment: Project interpreter is not necessarily the same as run time. EG: see what I posted, it came from the same project.

Comment: you are correct, print(sys.version) gives me 2.6.6. How do I set the runtime to be 3.5?